# How math function powr() from the frameworks RenderScript works?

Tags: renderscript

powr(2.0, 2.0) = 4.0
powr(-2.0, 2.0) = ?
Please tell me.
The documentation is not quite clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that the first parameter (base) needs to be between `0.f` and `256.f`. You can't use it with a negative input.

P.S. RenderScript has been deprecated - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate. You may want to consider this before writing further code using it.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I'm migrating a project from Renderscript to Vulkan.